# Float error python neural network

Tags: python, python-3.x, pybrain

I a new to python and neural networks. I tried using a sample code i found online on stack but i get errors. I have no idea why this is occurring. The following is the code i used.

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet,UnsupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.structure import LinearLayer
ds = SupervisedDataSet(21, 21)
ds.addSample(map(int,'1 2 4 6 2 3 4 5 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 7 1 2 3 5 6'.split()),map(int,'1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6'.split()))
ds.addSample(map(int,'1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6'.split()),map(int,'1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7'.split()))
net = buildNetwork(21, 20, 21, outclass=LinearLayer,bias=True, recurrent=True)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
trainer.trainEpochs(100)
ts = UnsupervisedDataSet(21,)
ts.addSample(map(int,'1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7'.split()))
[ int(round(i)) for i in net.activateOnDataset(ts)[0]]
```

the following is the errors i get:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7000795b45c6> in <module>()
      4 from pybrain.structure import LinearLayer
      5 ds = SupervisedDataSet(21, 21)
----> 6 ds.addSample(map(int,'1 2 4 6 2 3 4 5 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 7 1 2 3 5 6'.split()),map(int,'1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6'.split()))
      7 ds.addSample(map(int,'1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6'.split()),map(int,'1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7'.split()))
      8 net = buildNetwork(21, 20, 21, outclass=LinearLayer,bias=True, recurrent=True)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pybrain\datasets\supervised.py in addSample(self, inp, target)
     46     def addSample(self, inp, target):
     47         """Add a new sample consisting of `input` and `target`."""
---> 48         self.appendLinked(inp, target)
     49 
     50     def getSample(self, index=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pybrain\datasets\dataset.py in appendLinked(self, *args)
    214         assert len(args) == len(self.link)
    215         for i, l in enumerate(self.link):
--> 216             self._appendUnlinked(l, args[i])
    217 
    218     def getLinked(self, index=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pybrain\datasets\dataset.py in _appendUnlinked(self, label, row)
    196             self._resize(label)
    197 
--> 198         self.data[label][self.endmarker[label], :] = row
    199         self.endmarker[label] += 1
    200 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'map'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From a quick look at the [documentation](http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/dataset.html), try casting your `map` functions to `tuple`.

Comment: would be possible to give an example of what you mean

Comment: As suggested in below answer, you can do `tuple(map(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

The code works on `Python-2.x` but in `Python-3.x` you need to use `list` in order to call each item.

As an example:

> ds.addSample(**list**(map(int,'1 2 4 6 2 3 4 5 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 7 1 2 3 5
>   6'.split())),**list**(map(int,'1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3
>   6'.split())))

Updating all the example, works perfect:

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet,UnsupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.structure import LinearLayer
ds = SupervisedDataSet(21, 21)
ds.addSample(list(map(int,'1 2 4 6 2 3 4 5 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 7 1 2 3 5 6'.split())),list(map(int,'1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6'.split())))
ds.addSample(list(map(int,'1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6'.split())),list(map(int,'1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7'.split())))
net = buildNetwork(21, 20, 21, outclass=LinearLayer,bias=True, recurrent=True)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
trainer.trainEpochs(100)
ts = UnsupervisedDataSet(21,)
ts.addSample(list(map(int,'1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7'.split())))
print ([ int(round(i)) for i in net.activateOnDataset(ts)[0]])
```